# Find the coefficient of $x^{-2}$ in the expansion of $(x-1)^3(\frac{1}{x} +2x)^6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> Find the coefficient of $x^{-2}$ in the expansion of $(x-1)^3(\frac{1}{x} +2x)^6$.

I have tried finding out the general term of the whole expression.

Then, I get the result as such 
$$[(-1)^r {3 \choose r}(x^{3-r})][{6 \choose r} (2x)^{6-r}(\frac{1}{x})^r]$$
But after solving for I get $r = 11/3$

I think I am doing it wrong by just multiplying the general term. I don't know how else to continue. Please help.

Thank You!

Edit : *There was a typo in the question*

Comment: From the expression you put in the question, I'm wondering if you didn't miscopy the problem in the title.  Is there a missing power of 6 on the second term?

Comment: yes I have edited it now @MatthewLeingang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have\begin{align}\left(\frac1x+2x\right)^6&=\sum_{k=0}^6\binom6k\frac1{x^k}(2x)^{6-k}\\&=\sum_{k=0}^6\binom 6kx^{6-2k}2^{6-k}.\end{align}Here, the numbers that appear as exponents of $x$ belong to $\{-6,-4,-2,\ldots,6\}$. So, and since $(x-1)^3=x^3-3x^2+3x-1$ the coefficient of $x^{-2}$ in $(x-1)^3\left(\frac1x+2x\right)^6$ is the sum of these numbers:

- $-3\times\binom65\times2=-36$;
- $-\binom64\times2^2=-60$.

This sum is $-96$.

Answer (score 2):

We have \begin{align}(x-1)^3(\frac1x+2x)^6&=\left(\frac1x\right)^6(x-1)^3(1+2x^2)^6\\
&=\frac1{x^6}\left(\sum_{r=0}^3\binom3rx^{3-r}(-1)^r\right)\left(\sum_{s=0}^6\binom6s(2x^2)^s\right)\\
\end{align}

In order to get an exponent of $-2$, we can ignore the $\dfrac1{x^6}$ and look for an exponent of $4$ instead.  Therefore, we have $r=1$ and $s=1$, OR $r=3$ and $s=2$.

As such, we have $$\binom31(-1)^1\binom61(2)^1+\binom33(-1)^3\binom62(2)^2=\boxed{-96}.$$

Checking with [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+%28x-1%29%5E3%28%5Cfrac1x%2B2x%29%5E6) confirms the answer.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in the question

Comment: May I know why we should ignore $\frac{1}{x^6}$, please...?

Comment: $x^{-2}\div x^{-6}=x^4$, so by getting the coefficient of the $x^4$ term before multiplying by $\frac1{x^6}$, you will get the coefficient of the $x^{-2}$ term in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You have two binomial powers, so you need two separate binomial expansions.
\begin{align*}
    (x-1)^3\left(\frac{1}{x} + 2x\right)^6
    &= \sum_{r=0}^3 \binom{3}{r}(-1)^r x^{3-r}
       \sum_{s=0}^6 \binom{6}{s}(2x)^{6-s}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^s
  \\&= \sum_{r=0}^3\sum_{s=0}^6\binom{3}{r}\binom{6}{s}(-1)^r 2^{6-s} x^{(3-r)+(6-s)-s}
\end{align*}
If you want the coefficient of $x^{-2}$, you need to find the pairs $(r,s)$ with $0 \leq r \leq 3$ and $0 \leq s \leq 6$ such that
\begin{align*}
    (3-r)+(6-s) - s &= -2 \\
\iff
    9-r-2s &= -2 \\
\iff
    r+2s &= 11
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

*Hint.* Write the product as $$-x^{-6}(1-x)^3(1+2x^2)^6.$$ Then the general term is given by $$-x^{-6}{3\choose j}(-x)^j{6\choose k}(2x^2)^k,$$ with $0\le j\le 3,\,0\le k\le 6.$ To get the term in $x^{-2},$ you therefore need to have $-2=-6+j+2k,$ or $j+2k=4,$ whose solutions are given by $(j,k)=(0,2),\,(2,1).$ Thus you want to compute the coefficient $$(-1)^{j+1}2^k{3\choose j}{6\choose k}$$ for these two solutions and add them up.